# translate example is not working

Tags: admin-on-rest

I'm trying to use the example of [translating your own component](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Translation.html#translating-your-own-components)

so i'm doing this in `app.js`:

```
const messages = {
    en: {
        myroot: {
            hello: {
                world: 'Hello, World!',
            },
        },
    },
};
const App = () => (
  <Admin message={messages} locale="en" ...>
    <Resource name="myresource" edit={EditPage} />
```

and in my `Translation` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { translate } from 'admin-on-rest';

const Translation = ({ translate }) => (
    <button>{translate('myroot.hello.world')}</button>
);

export default translate(Translation);
```

finally in my `EditPage`:

```
import Translation from 'path/to/Translation';

export const EditPage = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props}>
    <Translation />
  </Edit>
);
```

its not working for me. its just showing `myroot.hello.world` in the button.

could you please help me out with that?

Answer (score 1):

Typo ?

`<Admin messages={messages} locale="en" ...>`

Note that the prop is `messages` and not `message`